# Timestamp is missing when I export dataset to CSV file

Tags: r

I am trying to export a dataset calculated in R to a CSV file.

I found that the first column `timestamp` is missing: it shows indexes instead!

How can I save the dataset along with `timestamp` to a CSV file?

Here is the original data looks like (dataset):

```
              timestamp      tr      ts
1   2015-07-08 02:29:00 1938.23 1978.62
2   2015-07-08 02:30:00 1936.74 1979.25
3   2015-07-08 02:31:00 1937.14 1978.99
4   2015-07-08 02:32:00 1937.66 1978.83
5   2015-07-08 02:33:00 1937.19 1979.15
6   2015-07-08 02:45:00 1937.00 1979.00
7   2015-07-08 02:46:00 1937.75 1979.29
8   2015-07-08 02:47:00 1937.84 1978.44
9   2015-07-08 02:48:00 1937.47 1979.17
10  2015-07-08 02:49:00 1937.82 1978.68
11  2015-07-08 02:50:00 1937.55 1979.60
12  2015-07-08 02:51:00 1937.55 1979.13
13  2015-07-08 02:52:00 1937.65 1979.12
14  2015-07-08 02:53:00 1937.56 1978.28
15  2015-07-08 02:54:00 1937.38 1978.99
16  2015-07-08 02:58:00 1937.86 1978.61
17  2015-07-08 02:59:00 1937.78 1978.85
18  2015-07-08 03:00:00 1937.71 1978.68
19  2015-07-08 03:01:00 1937.14 1979.04
20  2015-07-08 03:02:00 1936.86 1979.43
```

Here is the data after gapfilling looks like (df2):

```
                         tr      ts
2015-07-08 02:29:00 1938.23 1978.62
2015-07-08 02:30:00 1936.74 1979.25
2015-07-08 02:31:00 1937.14 1978.99
2015-07-08 02:32:00 1937.66 1978.83
2015-07-08 02:33:00 1937.19 1979.15
2015-07-08 02:34:00      NA      NA
2015-07-08 02:35:00      NA      NA
2015-07-08 02:36:00      NA      NA
2015-07-08 02:37:00      NA      NA
2015-07-08 02:38:00      NA      NA
2015-07-08 02:39:00      NA      NA
2015-07-08 02:40:00      NA      NA
2015-07-08 02:41:00      NA      NA
2015-07-08 02:42:00      NA      NA
2015-07-08 02:43:00      NA      NA
2015-07-08 02:44:00      NA      NA
2015-07-08 02:45:00 1937.00 1979.00
2015-07-08 02:46:00 1937.75 1979.29
2015-07-08 02:47:00 1937.84 1978.44
2015-07-08 02:48:00 1937.47 1979.17
2015-07-08 02:49:00 1937.82 1978.68
2015-07-08 02:50:00 1937.55 1979.60
2015-07-08 02:51:00 1937.55 1979.13
2015-07-08 02:52:00 1937.65 1979.12
2015-07-08 02:53:00 1937.56 1978.28
2015-07-08 02:54:00 1937.38 1978.99
2015-07-08 02:55:00      NA      NA
2015-07-08 02:56:00      NA      NA
```

Here is the csv file look likes (datatablefile.csv):

```
    tr  ts
1   1938.23 1978.62
2   1936.74 1979.25
3   1937.14 1978.99
4   1937.66 1978.83
5   1937.19 1979.15
6   NA  NA
7   NA  NA
8   NA  NA
9   NA  NA
10  NA  NA
11  NA  NA
12  NA  NA
13  NA  NA
14  NA  NA
15  NA  NA
16  NA  NA
17  1937    1979
18  1937.75 1979.29
19  1937.84 1978.44
20  1937.47 1979.17
21  1937.82 1978.68
22  1937.55 1979.6
23  1937.55 1979.13
24  1937.65 1979.12
25  1937.56 1978.28
26  1937.38 1978.99
27  NA  NA
28  NA  NA
29  NA  NA
```

Here is my code:

```
# make path to the csv file
fpath <- file.path("test_gapfilling.csv"); 

# read the csv file
dataset <- read.csv(fpath, header=TRUE);

# reformat timestamp
dataset$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(dataset$timestamp, format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M")

#set date to Index
df1.zoo <- zoo(dataset[,-1], dataset[,1]);

#merge two datasets 
df2 <- merge(df1.zoo, zoo(,seq(start(df1.zoo), end(df1.zoo), by="min")), all=TRUE)

# export to a csv file
write.csv(df2, file='datatablefile.csv')
```

Comment: It is hard to help you with the code you have posted because in fact it is useless and does not allow us to help you. Maybe the data that are not shown are just row names. It could be a good thing to add them with the `add_rownames` function of the `dplyr` package. But that is just an idea.

Comment: When you say `timestamp`, you mean number of seconds since epoch or just the date in the original format: `"%m/%d/%y %H:%M"`? It would help if you share a part of your input data and expected output explicitly with your question.

Comment: dataset added. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `write.csv` you need to use `write.zoo` along with specifying the appropriate valuefor `index.name` parameter. For you case you can use the following code line to write a csv with `TIMESTAMP` being the `index.name`.

```
write.zoo(df2, file = 'datatablefile.csv', index.name = 'TIMESTAMP', sep = ',', col.names = T)
```

HTH

Comment: You are very helpful. Thank you so much!!